# Excel macro buttons dissapear after screen resizing

Tags: microsoft-excel, resolution, macros

I use an excel workbook (made by someone else). Many years ago I used to program excel files with buttons and stuff, but now I don't remember even the terminology so please take that into account

The thing is I have worked with these workbooks without problems so far. Everytime I press the button some recalculation happens.

Lately on a unrelated thing I had to resize my screen (from 150% to 100%).

I did some unrelated work and then opened the excel workbook. I could see the button but after I pressed it it got smaller. eventually it dissapeared.

Fortunately I had a backup so back when I return to 150% I could make a copy of the backup and work with the copy no problem but I wonder why is the button dissapearing and how can you get the button back (Right clicking on it does not work)

Comment: This is happening due to Zoom in or resizing the display to 100%, since the Macro is working properly when the Zoom is 150%, what I would like to suggest that Copy the Macro VBA code & Paste it as standard module with the Sheet, RUN it as macro not through Command Button.

Comment: Going into it while in Design Mode has worked for me when buttons get flacky.  Select Developer on Ribbon and click on Design Mode in the Controls group.  (If you don't have Developer in your Ribbon:  right click on the Ribbon, select `Customize the Ribbon...`, in `Choose commands from:` select Main Tabs, and add Developer.)  Once in Design Mode you should be able to right-click.  I would suggest that you check `Format Control`, `Properties` and play with the Object Positioning to see if that will improve the behavior.  `Move and size with cells` seems to work best for me with resize.

Comment: Oh yes, you will need to click on Design Mode when you are done to get out of the mode or you won't be able to use your buttons.